# CMake cannot find OpenSSL libraries in windows

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl

This is my cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)

set(PACKAGE_NAME "atest")

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)

project(${PACKAGE_NAME} LANGUAGES C CXX)
```

I have a custom openssl binary that I wanna use in a folder

```
C:\MyOpenSSL\
C:\MyOpenSSL\include\ ... all the include files here
C:\MyOpenSSL\lib\ ... libssl.lib, libcrypto.lib and ossl_static.pdb
```

So when I run, `CMake . -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=C:\MyOpenSSL\`
I get the following errors:

```
C:/cmake/cmake-3.22.2-win/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY) (found
  version "1.1.1c")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/cmake/cmake-3.22.2-win/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/cmake/cmake-3.22.2-win/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:574 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)
```

What am I missing here? Is somehow find_package found out the version v1.1.1c, but still saying it couldn't find it?

Comment: Which [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) are you using? E.g. with MinGW you are unlikely can use `.lib` libraries. In other words, make sure that OpenSSL libraries are pre-built with the same compiler as the one you use for your project.

Comment: Interesting. My colleagues told me that the libraries are generated via visual studio. Does that mean I need to pass cmake some argument to use visual studio generator?

Comment: Usually, if Visual Studio is installed, then CMake uses it by default. In any case, you could pass `cmake` a `-G` option with corresponding [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out if I build and install openssl manually it works.
For whatever reason the raw lib i provided was not good enough for cmake to find it. I am still not sure why.